# How to make a plugin goal run regardless of test failures

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a plugin that is supposed to send files to a database regardless of test failures. I tried setting the fail-at-end setting but the plugin still didn't run. ignoring failures altogether doesn't seem to be an option for me in this case because then faulty jars would be deployed to the artifact repository. I can use this plugin for as a separate command line script but it would be optimal if it could be put in the pom.

The tests need to be run before the plugin does, because the plugin gets the test report files.

I am aware that there are similar questions to this that have been asked before, but they don't seem to help me so I was wondering if someone has similar advice.

Comment: Please show the pom file and show the plugin your are mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin has to run after the tests, the tests just can't fail the build.

Maven Surefire plugin has an option: **maven.test.failure.ignore** to run the tests but keep execution

See [Here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) a full description of Test MOJO.

This should be the first bet.

Another option is to build just like this, but run the plugin "externally" (a kind of two steps build). Run **maven install** or whatever you need, and then (separately)

```
mvn <group>:<artifact>:<version>:<mojo of your plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `mvn your-goal -DskipTests` - will ignore testing.

Comment: i forgot to say it originally, but it has to get the test results and send them to the database so i can't skip the tests.